# Xtext - Java 64K limitation in generated Parser

Tags: xtext

I'm working on a quite large grammar and it looks like I have a problem with the Java 64K limitation.

The Mwe2 configuration needs about 1024MB Heap for the generation, but after about 6 minutes, an error message is reported: "The code of constructor x() is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit".

As the Java 64K limitation is a known issue, so I quickly found some solutions and configured the workflow with the following:

```
fragment = parser.antlr.XtextAntlrGeneratorFragment auto-inject {
    antlrParam = "-Xconversiontimeout" antlrParam = "60000"
    options = {
        classSplitting=true
        fieldsPerClass = "200"
        methodsPerClass= "500"
    }
}

fragment = parser.antlr.XtextAntlrUiGeneratorFragment auto-inject {
    antlrParam = "-Xconversiontimeout" antlrParam = "60000"
    options = {
        classSplitting=true
        fieldsPerClass = "500"
        methodsPerClass= "500"
    }
    partialParsing=true
}
```

But nothing has changed. The removing of partialParsing also doesn't have any effect.

Has anyone already face the same and could give me a tip for this issue?
Is there something I could do about this error?

Thanks

Comment: I figured out, that it has to do with the variable nameMappings. Obviously I have to many rules and alternatives in my grammar, so it reaches the 64k limitation of Java because every single rule and it's alternatives are added to this variable. Shouldn't the settings in XtextAntlrGeneratorFragment and XtextAntlrUiGeneratorFragment prevent this?